# wallet or node installed

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

After downloading and installing Ethereum wallet for mac from [Ethereum web site](https://www.ethereum.org/)
When I start the app, I get the initialisation screen saying "Ethereum node needs to sync, Downloading block.., Downloading chain structure...".

But I am not doing mining. why a wallet has to do a node sync and get blocks and chain...? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mist (the ethereum wallet you downloaded) requires a full node to be functional. So you have to wait for it to finish syncing.

You can interact with the ethereum blockchain without downloading a full node using different ethereum wallets like [Metamask](https://metamask.io/) or [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/).

Comment: Does that mean I can technically use this wallet for mining as well?

Comment: @FredJ. Well you can't mine without having a full node (Unless you use some third party service). So having a full node already synced will make it much easier but there's still some steps to take to start mining.

Comment: I am not planing to use my MacBook to do mining, it is not practical. Also the other question I forgot to ask. Every time I start the app, will it take "that" much time to download and sync?

Comment: @FredJ. No once it's synced it will be pretty quick to open depending on how long you haven't opened Mist.